# What is the correct way to use the `watch` function from `vue` when using multiple reactive values?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, reactive, watch

For example, in React, when using useEffect, if bar is not registered in the dependency array, the exhaustive-deps error occurs, as follows:

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = useState("foo")
const [bar, setBar] = useState("bar")

useEffect(() => {
  if (foo === 'something' && bar !== 'anything') {
    console.log({ foo, bar })
  }
}, [foo]) // Error: react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

but in Vue, the following code does not result in an error

```js
const foo = ref('foo');
const bar = ref('bar');

watch(foo, (newFoo) => {
  if (bar.value !== 'bar') {
    console.log(newFoo)
  }
})
```

in my opinion, all reactive variables used in the following manner should be observed

```js
const foo = ref('foo');
const bar = ref('bar');

watch([foo, bar], ([newFoo, newBar]) => {
  if (newBar !== 'bar') {
    console.log(newFoo)
  }
})
```

However, even after searching on Google or looking at the official documentation, it is difficult to find an answer for this. What is the correct way to do this and why?

---

I also wrote the following code to test for errors that may occur when not observing all dependencies, but I don't feel like I've really found the real reason.

-> [link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const foo = ref('foo')
const bar = ref('bar')
const fooChecked = ref(false)
const isBarNotBar = ref(false)

const foo2 = ref('foo2')
const bar2 = ref('bar2')
const foo2Checked = ref(false)
const isBar2NotBar = ref(false)

watch(foo, (newFoo) => {
  fooChecked.value = true
  if (bar.value !== 'bar') {
    isBarNotBar.value = true
  }
})
  
watch([foo2, bar2], ([newFoo2, newBar2]) => {
  foo2Checked.value = true
  if (newBar2 !== 'bar') {
    isBar2NotBar.value = true
  }
})
  
////
function changeBarAsync(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    bar.value = 'newBar'
  }, 0)
}
  
function changeBar2Async(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    bar2.value = 'newBar'
  }, 0)
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
    {{ foo }} | {{ bar }}
    <div :style="isBarNotBar ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'green' }">
      {{ isBarNotBar ? 'bar is not bar' : 'bar is bar' }}{{ fooChecked ? ' ✅' : '' }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button @click="() => foo = 'newFoo'">
    change foo
  </button>
  <button @click="() => { foo = 'newFoo'; bar = 'newBar'}">
    change foo and bar
  </button>
  <button @click="() => { foo = 'newFoo'; changeBarAsync(); }">
    change foo and bar async
  </button>
  <br >
  <br >
  <div :style="{ width: '100%', height: '1px', backgroundColor: '#777' }"></div>
  <br >
  <div>
    {{ foo2 }} | {{ bar2 }}
    <div :style="isBar2NotBar ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'green' }">
      {{ isBar2NotBar ? 'bar is not bar' : 'bar is bar' }}{{ foo2Checked ? ' ✅' : '' }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button @click="() => foo2 = 'newFoo'">
    change foo2
  </button>
  <button @click="() => { foo2 = 'newFoo'; bar2 = 'newBar'}">
    change foo2 and bar2
  </button>
  <button @click="() => { foo2 = 'newFoo'; changeBar2Async(); }">
    change foo2 and bar2 async
  </button>
  <br >
</template>
```

Comment: its a design choice, if you want all the refs used in the watch callback to be watched then use `watchEffect` and if you want to be explicit about what is exactly watched then use `watch`.
imo this is better since you can mutate refs -that are used inside the watch callback but not explicitly tracked - somewhere else in the code safely without fearing them triggering the watch callback.

Comment: The answer to your question is actually quite simple. Do you want to trigger your side effects when `foo` changes or do you want to trigger it when EITHER `foo` or `bar` changes? As mentioned by @SherifHassan, it is a design choice. Furthermore, both React and Vue handle their reactivity differently. While React re-renders the entire component when a state changes, Vue is more fine-grained. This is why Vue requires you to be explicit when declaring side effects, computed variables, etc.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula @SherifHassan In this case, I understood it to be a case where we need to track both `foo` and `bar`. or use `watchEffect`. But if `foo` is explicitly being tracked in the `watch` callback and `bar` is also used in the callback, shouldn't that be a problem? but it wouldn't throw an error or warning. What I'm saying is, shouldn't we explicitly track every single ref you reference in callback?

Comment: @BoHyeonSeo why would it be a problem? when using `watch` in vue you don't have to explicitly track every ref used inside the callback, you only need to track those you want to be tracked

Comment: @SherifHassan Doesn't ref mean that we want the changes to be reflected in the view as well? so if we don't keep track of all the refs we use in our callbacks, the ref value we used inside the `watch` callback might be different from the one we used in the current view?